# Writing every two items in a list to a text file, then creating a new line

Tags: python, list, loops, text-files

Full script essentially opens a txt file with three columns separated by a whitespace and saves it to a list *words*

```
with open(filename) as f:
    words = f.read().split()
```

Every third item is deleted from the list starting from position 2 using: `del words[2::3]`

The next step I would like to add is writing to the same filename with two of the three columns (or every two items in *words*), space them out and then create a new line in a text file:

`('list_item1' + ' ' + 'list_item2' + '/n'), ('list_item3' + ' ' + 'list_item4' + '/n')`, etc

Any help would be appreciated!

I've thus far only been able to split text from the text file into a list but would like to take every two items from that list and write to text file using the format: `('list_item1/3/5etc' + ' ' + 'list_item2/4/6etc' + '/n')`

```
with open(r'filename', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(" ".join(str(item) for item in words))
```

Comment: Format your codes. put ` ` around one line code & ``` ``` around multiline

Comment: What's your question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an iterator for the list, and use the `next` function inside the loop to get the next element from the iterator.

```
my_lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
list_iter = iter(my_lst)
with open(file_name, "w") as fp:
    for item in list_iter:
        try:
            item2 = next(list_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            fp.write(f"{item}\n")
        else:
            fp.write(f"{item} {item2}\n")
```

Which writes a file with:

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

The `item2` line is wrapped in a `try..except` to catch the `StopIteration` that is thrown if the list iterator has been exhausted. In this case, only the first item is written to the file. If no `StopIteration` is thrown, the `else` block is executed, which writes both items and a newline to the file

---

A more general implementation of this would be to use a function that gives chunks of the desired size from your original list:

```
def chunks(collection, chunk_size):
    l = [] # An empty list to hold the current chunk
    for item in collection:
        l.append(item) # Append item to the current chunk
        if len(l) == chunk_size:
            yield l    # If chunk is of required size, yield it
            l = []     # Set current chunk to new empty list

    # Yield the chunk containing any remaining items
    if l: 
        yield l
```

See [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) for more information on what `yield` does.

Iterating over this function yields lists of `chunk_size` elements. We can just take these lists, join them with a space, and write them to the file:

```
with open(file_name, "w") as fp:
    for chunk in chunks(my_lst, 2):
        fp.write(" ".join(chunk))
        fp.write("\n")
```

Or, in a single line (ugh)

```
with open(file_name, "w") as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join(" ".join(chunk) for chunk in chunks(my_lst, 2)))
```